# Union of multiple tables, each with a single unique column

Tags: postgresql

I have a number of tables with data values. They all have a number of columns in common but also a unique column each:

```
TableA = id, value, source, destination_a
TableB = id, value, source, destination_b
TableC = id, value, source, destination_c
TableD = id, value, source, destination_d
...
```

I want to create a view of all this data, something like:

```
TableV = id, value, source, destination_a, destination_b, destination_c, destination_d
```

Where the `destination_X` for each row are `NULL` if they didn't come from that table.

I've tried nulling the columns manually, for example (with only two of the above tables):

```
CREATE VIEW TableV AS
SELECT id, value, source, destination_a NULL AS destination_b FROM TableA UNION
SELECT id, value, source, destination_b NULL AS destination_a FROM TableB
```

But this leaves one column entirely blank.

How can I create a table that is a union of all these tables, but with all N columns included and appropriately nulled?

```
TableV | id | value | source | destination_a | destination_b
         a0    a1      a2      a3              NULL
         b1    b2      b3      NULL            b4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the issue here was simply with how I was ordering the `SELECT`. I should have had:

```
CREATE VIEW TableV AS
SELECT id, value, source, destination_a NULL AS destination_b FROM TableA UNION
SELECT id, value, source, NULL AS destination_a, destination_b FROM TableB
```

I was putting the `NULL as ...` at the end of each select

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure if this would apply to PostgresSQL, but for SQL-Server, something like this I think would work:

```
CREATE VIEW TableV AS
SELECT id, value, source, destination_a as [A],NULL as [B],NULL as [C], NULL as [D]
    FROM TableA UNION
SELECT id, value, source, NULL as [A],destination_b  as [B],NULL as [C], NULL as [D]
    FROM TableB UNION
SELECT id, value, source, NULL as [A],NULL as [B],destination_c  as [C], NULL as [D]
    FROM TableC UNION
SELECT id, value, source, NULL as [A],NULL as [B],NULL as [C], destination_d as [D]
    FROM TableD
```